# Can we make the 2fa tag a synonym of multi-factor?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I've been trying to kill the [2fa](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2fa) tag for a while, but it keeps comming back from the dead. We already have the tag [multi-factor](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-factor) and I see no meaningful distinction that would be upheld by people tagging questions.

Could someone with the right priveliges (mods?) make [2fa](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2fa) a synonym of [multi-factor](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-factor)?

Comment: How does it work? Do I make 2fa a synonym of multi-factor, the other way around, or does it matter?

Comment: @schroeder I think 2fa should be a synonym of multi-factor. So that we keep the old multi-factor tag as the "real" tag that synonyms point to.

Comment: Oh, I see the dependency now.

Comment: The system is blocking the link to `multi-factor` because there is already a link between that and `two-factor-auth` and I can't link `2fa` to either.

Comment: Weird! I tried suggesting 2fa as a synonym [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/tags/multi-factor/synonyms), but apparently "version specific synonyms can only be proposed by moderators". Must be the 2 messing it up there.